# Laravel Eloquent: Show Tasks for Another User in Group

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have Users, Groups and Tasks.

A user can haveMany Tasks and belongToMany Groups.

For the active user, I want to show all tasks for *other users* that are in the active user's groups.

I do have a task_user pivot table with group_id and user_id in place, just not sure how to query that relationship with Eloquent.

**Edit:**

Getting very close.

If I use:

```
$groupTasks = Task::with('user.groups')->get();
```

I get a JSON object with the task info, the associated user, and that user's groups:

```
{
    id: "1",
    user_id: "1",
    name: "Clean Garage"
    user: {
        id: "1",
        username: "user",
        email: "user@example.com",
        groups: [{
            id: "1",
            name: "Boulder",
            pivot: {
                user_id: "1",
                group_id: "1",
                status: "Active"
            }
        }, {
            id: "3",
            name: "Lafeyette",
            pivot: {
                user_id: "1",
                group_id: "3",
                status: "Active"
            }
        }, {
            id: "4",
            name: "Longmont",
            pivot: {
                user_id: "1",
                group_id: "4",
                status: "Active"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

But, I'm still not sure how to filter that request so that it returns only tasks where the task's user is in one of my groups.

Comment: Hey, how far have you got?  Can you share any code with us?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding a couple of things. How are you determining the "active" user, and when you say you have a `task_user` pivot table, why do you have `group_id` in that pivot table? it should only be `task_id` and `user_id`.